# nginx ingress routing (default backend 404)

Tags: kubernetes, routes, nginx-ingress

I am trying to write an ingress for a rest api service but I am seeing "default backend 404"

my rest service url is like this
https://myurl.com/restsvc/api/test/v1/app/hello?name=bob

below is my ingress yml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: restservice-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myurl.com
      secretName: secret
  rules:
    - host: myurl.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /restsvc/api/test/v1/app/(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: restservice-svc
              servicePort: 8080
```

Any help appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by using the below rewrite target

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: staging-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myurl.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /restsvc(/|$)(.*)
        backend: 
          serviceName: restservice-svc
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myurl.com
      secretName: secret
```

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: staging-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myurl.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /restsvc/api/test/v1/app/(.*)
        backend: 
          serviceName: restservice-svc
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myurl.com
      secretName: secret
```

Comment: tried this, now I am seeing a different error message 
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Comment: is your application a springboot application ?

Comment: try adding and hitting some routes into you restservice-svc, the control shall come there, the error page you saw is likely because the URI may not be existing

Comment: without ingress, I can access the urls